# populate multiple fields in SelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
 ViewBag.partners = new SelectList(db.PRT_PARTNERS, "ID", "FIRST_NAME", "LAST_NAME");
```

*db* is my database object

*PRT_PARTNERS* is the table

*ID* is the field which must select

and *FIRST_NAME* is the field which will text in dropdownlist

can i populate it like this?

```
ViewBag.partners = new SelectList(db.PRT_PARTNERS, "ID", "FIRST_NAME + LAST_NAME");
```

Comment: Create a collection of anonymous objects with the `ID` and concatenated values of `FIRST_NAME` and `LAST_NAME`, then generate the `SelectList` from that collection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do but you have to project it in memory first using [`Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548743%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var partners = db.PRT_PARTNERS.Select(x=> 
                                   new 
                                      { 
                                        ID =x.ID,
                                        Name = x.First_Name +" "+ x.Last_Name
                                    });

ViewBag.partners = new SelectList(partners , "ID", "Name");
```